# MongoDB Collection Level Access Control not working

Tags: mac-osx, mongodb, access-control-list

I have to restrict few MongoDB users to specific collections with some specific action permissions(only Update collection). As per the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/) it's possible.

```
localhost:tmp username$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.1
Server has startup warnings: 
2018-05-06T15:30:51.739+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-05-06T15:30:51.772+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-05-06T15:30:51.772+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-05-06T15:30:51.772+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> 
> 
> 
> use foo
switched to db foo
> db.inventory.insertOne(    { item: "canvas", qty: 100, tags: ["cotton"], size: { h: 28, w: 35.5, uom: "cm" } } )
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedId" : ObjectId("5af6c7e058d94deb0777e883")
}
> 
> 
> 
> db.inventory.find( { item: "canvas" } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5af6c7e058d94deb0777e883"), "item" : "canvas", "qty" : 100, "tags" : [ "cotton" ], "size" : { "h" : 28, "w" : 35.5, "uom" : "cm" } }
> 
> 
> 
> show collections
inventory
> db.createRole({ role: "fooRole", privileges: [ { resource: { db: "foo", collection: "inventory" }, actions: [ "find", "update" ] } ], roles: [] })
{
    "role" : "fooRole",
    "privileges" : [
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "foo",
                "collection" : "inventory"
            },
            "actions" : [
                "find",
                "update"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "roles" : [ ]
}
> 
> 
> 
> 
> db.createUser({ user: "foouser", pwd: "foopass", roles: [ { role: "fooRole", db: "foo" } ] })
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "foouser",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "fooRole",
            "db" : "foo"
        }
    ]
}
> 
> 
> 
bye
```

Logging in as the foouser,

```
localhost:tmp username$ mongo -u "foouser" -p "foopass" --authenticationDatabase "foo" 
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.1
Server has startup warnings: 
2018-05-06T15:30:51.739+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-05-06T15:30:51.772+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-05-06T15:30:51.772+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-05-06T15:30:51.772+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> 
> 
> use foo
switched to db foo
> show collections
inventory
> db.inventory.drop()
true
> show collections
> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "foo", "ok" : 1 }
> 
bye
```

If I should tell briefly what I did above,

- Created 'foo' database with a collection 'inventory'
- Created a role 'fooRole' with 'find' & 'update' -
  `db.createRole({ role: "fooRole", privileges: [ { resource: { db: "foo", collection: "inventory" }, actions: [ "find", "update" ] } ], roles: [] })`
- Created user 'foouser' with role 'fooRole'      - 
  `db.createUser({ user: "foouser", pwd: "foopass", roles: [ { role: "fooRole", db: "foo" } ] })`

Why it doesn't work?. Why `foouser` can drop collection and database?
Am I doing anything wrong?. Please suggest some solution!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have created users, the startup warning in your transcript indicates you haven't enabled access control:

```
** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
**          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
```

As at MongoDB 3.6, access control must be explicitly enabled using the [`security.authorization`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization) configuration setting or the `--auth` command line option.

For full steps, see the [Enable Auth tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) in the MongoDB manual.

Comment: Oops... didn't know auth has to be enabled first. Thank you!